# Sorting an array of information from another array output from SQL

Tags: php

I need to be retrieve multiple unique values from an array set of data. Currently they are extracted as follows :

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    { 

     echo    "<tr>".
             "<td>".$row1[0]           . "</td>".
             "<td>".$row1[1]           . "</td>".
             "<td>".$row1[2]           . "</td>".
             "<td>".$row1[3]           . "</td>".        
             "<td>".$row1[4]           . "</td>".
             "<td>".$row1[5]           . "</td>".
             "<td>".$row1[6]           . "</td>".
             "<td>".$row1[7]           . "</td>".
//$row1[8] is the number of hours
             "<td>".$row1[8]           . "</td>".
//$row1[9] is the user
             "<td>".$row1[9]           . "</td>";
             }
```

As commented above, I need to accumulate the hours per user. However, I have problem sorting the array as the user value has to be unique in the array whereas the number has to keep stacking.

Really confused now. Appreciate any help offered.

EDIT : $row1[8] is an integer yes.

The sample data output table ( sorry no image) will be as follows :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Users |Telephone | Address | Postal Code | Hobbies | Interest| FB |Twitter | Insta | Hours
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John  | 92238726 | SG      | 345322      | Running | Movies  |  1 |   0    | 0     |  5
Tom  | 922382134 | MY      | 345212      | Soccer | Movies  |  1 |   0    | 0      |  8
Jerry | 92238726 | SG      | 342122      | stamps | Nil  |  0 |   1    | 0      |   5
John  | 92238726 | SG      | 345322      | Running | Movies  |  1 |   0    | 0     |  12
Jerry | 92238726 | SG      | 342122      | stamps | Nil  |  0 |   1    | 0      |   2
```

Based on the output above which was extracted with the mysql_fetch_array, I'd like to sort the information to something like the following :

```
Users | Total Hours
John  |    17
Tom   |     8
Jerry |    7
```

SQL CODE :

```
"select DISTINCT jl.refno, jl.logno, jl.attendee, jl.jobsummary, FROM_UNIXTIME(jl.date, '%d/%m/%y') AS 'Date-In', from_unixtime(jl.dateout + (15*3600), '%d/%m/%y') AS 'Date-Out', @timein := (left(jl.timein,2)*60+right(jl.timein,2)) AS 'Time-In', @timeout := (left(jl.timeout,2)*60+right(timeout,2)) AS 'Time-Out', @temp := ((dateout -date)* 24 * 60) + @timeout - @timein AS 'temp', us.username from joblog jl, projects proj, users us where jl.project ='{$value}' AND proj.id ='{$value}' AND jl.staff = us.id"
```

Comment: What does your data look like $row1[8], is it an integer? How do you want to sort? Any sample data and display?

Comment: your table structure + more coding would really help.. This is like asking people to use their glass ball in the hope we can see your future..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MySQL anyway, I recommend you to do it with an SQL. It's cleaner.

Edit your query to:

```
SELECT users, SUM(hours) as total FROM userTable GROUP BY users ORDER BY total DESC;
```

UPDATE - PHP Edition:

You can do it like this in PHP.

```
$counters = array();
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $counters[$row1[9]] += $rows1[8];
}

arsort($counters);

foreach ($counters as $name => $total) {
   // do your output here
}
```

Comment: Hi my current SQL is rather complex to do this trick of yours. Any way to do at php level ? I attached my SQL statement in the edits

Comment: hi @daniel cheng thanks for your reply. How ever the result wasn't what i wanted. I need the total hours to be accumulative. Meaning John had 17 hours etc etc. This code currently doesnt allow that. Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

function totalHours($user){
$result=mysql_query("select sum(hours) as total  from table_name where users='".$user."'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
return $row['total'];
    }

$result=mysql_query("select * from table_name group by users");
echo "</table>";
echo "<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>Total Hours</td>
</tr>";

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    { 

 echo    "<tr>".
         "<td>".$row1[0]. "</td>".
        "<td>".totalHours($row1[0]). "</td></tr>";

         }

        echo "</table>";             
?>
```

Comment: replace table_name by your table name